# Why am I getting this error {"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."} C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I have built an SSRS report which summarizes my data in the form of count data and cost data.  The Text boxes where I show this data have an action setup to open a more detailed report using parameters passed from the Summary report.  These reports function as desired when viewed on the SSRS server.

Now I have a web application that uses C# to manage the data input for these reports and  I am using a aspx ReportViewer  to display these reports within the application.  The problem is if I open the summary report from my C# web application and then click on the link to open the detailed report the screen changes and it looks like it going to open the detail report but then it just sits there and does not render the report.

When I run the application from Visual Studios on my LocalHost I get this error message when I try to open the Summary Report; {"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."}

Here is the C# code that I am using:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get the report server url from web.config
    String reportServerUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ReportServerUrl");
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new System.Uri(reportServerUrl);

    String report = Request.QueryString["r"];
    if (report == "TransportTotals")
    {
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/ExTraReports/TransportTotals";
        this.Title = "Transport Totals Report";
    }
```

Can anyone provide an explanation of what is going wrong with the report?

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: Here is some it:   at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: Please edit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem.  the corrected code is below:

```
String report = Request.QueryString["r"];
    if (report == "TransportTotals" && ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath != "/ExTraReports/NEWClosedTransportsByStateAndAgencyTypeAndNameDetail")
    {
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/ExTraReports/TransportTotals";
        this.Title = "Transport Totals Report";
    }
```

I had to check the report path that is being returned each time the page loads to see if we were calling the detail report, which has a different path.  If so It then fails the if block and opens the linked report.